# Call an attribute from a Matlab script in AppDesigner GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have created a GUI with app designer which launch a matlab program after the user chose a file and pressed launch button :

```
function LaunchButtonPushed(app, event)

    app.ResultWindowTextArea.BackgroundColor = 'green';
    app.ResultWindowTextArea.FontSize = 20;
    app.ResultWindowTextArea.Value = 'Launch of the program ...';
    testLectureXML(app.FileTextArea.Value{:});
    if n_component == 0
         app.ResultWindowTextArea.BackgroundColor = 'red';
         app.ResultWindowTextArea.Value = 'Please choose a valid File !';
         stop testLectureXML()
    end
end
```

`n_component` is an attribute in my `testLectureXML` matlab program and he is equal to 0 only if the file that the user chose is empty. But it's like my application doesn't recognize `n_component`as the attribute of my `testLectureXML`program.

And if possible, if `n_component = 0` i would like to stop the program

How can i do  this ? Thanks !

Edit : To stop the programm i have thinking of creating `exitProgram = 0 and if exitProgram = 1 return 0`and in the GUI code i just put `exitProgram = 1` if the file is empty but i don't know how to access to an attribute of a matlab script with GUI code.

Comment: It looks to me that `testLectureXML` is a function, not a program. Neither functions nor programs have attributes, they use variables. Variables in a function are local to that function, you cannot see the outside the function. But you can have the function return the value. Then you'd do `n_component = testLectureXML(...);`.

Comment: The fact is testLectureXML() is not returning n_component it's just a variable i need to access in my app designer code :/

Comment: If it is an internal variable in `testLectureXML`, and you want access to it, then you must have that function return it. There is no way of reading a variable that is inside another function. I cannot help you further because I don’t know anything about your program. You should post a [mcve] if you want a real answer.

Comment: It's ok i found my answer i didn't know that with matlab we have to do function outout = name(input)